# Why my custom plugin works only after be visited once in cordova (phonegap)?

Tags: cordova, plugins

I created a custom plugin using the roles of cordova. I have added the plugin's key/value to cordova.plist and  writen the plugin in native ios code.  But I can get the result only after I visited the fllowing page once. I don't know where went wrong. If the cordova js needs some  initialization ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Overview</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    *{  margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body {
        margin-left:0px;
        width:1024px;
        background-image: url("content/main/defaultbg.jpg");
        background-size:1024px 768px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="slr_left_title">
    html code ....
   </div>
<script>

setTimeout(function(){

   window.getReportList = function(reportCategory, successCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, function(err) {
                    callback('get the category list error！');
                    }, "SLReportList", "getlist", [reportCategory]);
   };

   window.getReportList("atestcategory", function(result) {
              alert(result);
   });
},0);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know exactly what's going wrong without knowing what your plugin is trying to do and seeing its code, but here's my best guess.

Cordova plugins are loaded lazily, on-demand. So your plugin won't be active until you call `exec()` on it at least once. If your plugin is one intended to occasionally call into Javascript with information, without the Javascript asking for it each time, then you'll need to call an `initialize` method on the plugin with `exec()` at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

As of Cordova 2.5.0, you can add `onload="true"` to that plugin's entry in cordova's config xml.

See http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html